# Problem in Python Request receiving status code 400

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests, devops

I am using Python Request to send metrics to promethus.
I received Status 400 for this Code.

```
import requests
job_name='xxx'
response = requests.post('http://x.x.x.x:9091/metrics/job/{j}/'.format(j=job_name), data={'payload_key':'cpu_utilization','payload_value':'30.0'})
print(response.status_code)
```

Someone Help me in this

Comment: `400 Bad Request` - How can we possible know which parameters and values `http://x.x.x.x:9091/metrics/job/{j}/` expects?

Comment: Are you sure you want to send a string for the `payload_value` instead of a float? It is also possible that your endpoint is only accepting JSON bodies.

Comment: Also, did you try using the [official tools](https://github.com/prometheus/client_python#exporting-to-a-pushgateway) to communicate with prometheus?